# how to align grid Panel in center

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

I am placing Ext JS Grid Panel in a iFrame. Do anybody know how can I place it in the center of the iFrame.

Currently It look like this -
[image: Currently It look like this]

I want it to be like this -
[image: I want it to be like this]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The contents of your IFrame can use a border layout as above or no layout, like this:

```
var viewPort = new Ext.Viewport({
    renderTo:'body',
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    items:[new Ext.Panel({
        title: 'hi',
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        style: 'margin:0 auto;margin-top:100px;'
    })]
```

});

Comment: Thanks Skym. one more question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594067/align-components-in-the-center-in-a-panel-ext-js

Answer (score 3):

In the [examples site](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html) there is an example that does this you may want to look at.

```
layout:'ux.center',
items: {
    title: 'Centered Panel',
    widthRatio: 0.75,
    html: 'Some content'
}
```

Comment: apparently this has side-effects http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?65064-SOLVED-!!!-ux.center-not-work

Answer (score 1):

Another way, not as elegant, is a cludge of VBox and HBox layouts but is pure ExtJS and doesn't rely on UX:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport',{
    style: 'background-color: white;',

    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align : 'stretch',
        pack  : 'start',
    },
    items: [{
        flex: 1,
        border: false
    },{
        height: 200,
        border: false,
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            pack: 'start',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [{
            flex: 1,
            border: false
        },{
            html:'Centered Panel',
            width: 400
        },{
            flex: 1,
            border: false
        }]
    },{
        flex: 1,
        border: false
    }]

    //items: [login_panel],

});
```

Answer (score 1):

simply use:

```
this.center()
```

where as "this" is the object you want to put in the center (let's say grid).

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
grid:
  region: center;

panel:
  layout: border;
  css: "padding: 40px"
```